# Swift 4: How to perform segue in viewDidLoad in VC1 inside a navigation controller to VC2 that has no navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, swift4

I have VC1 which is a tableVC inside a navVC. I have a button that modally presents VC2 which is not inside a navVC.

In some cases I want to present VC2 in `viewDidLoad`.

I've tried putting the below in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` as well as a bunch of other things but I cannot get VC2 to show up on launch.

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "launchSegue", sender: self)
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

---

Sorry if this is a duplicate but I've looked around and can't find anything. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974858/how-to-present-a-view-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-swift) is the closest I've come but its trying to present to a nav so its kind of the opposite way.

Comment: Why the link you've defined is not working for you for presenting the VC2 modally? Do you need to have the VC2 in the navVC viewControllers stack or what?

Comment: Right now when I click a button to present VC to it stacks over top of the nav and everything(so the nav is not visible when VC 2 is open). 

I'd like it to present VC 2 the exact same way on launch of the app when an array is empty. The logic for if the array is empty is simple. I'm just having trouble programmatically performing the segue.

Comment: In this case, if I got you right, you have at least two options: 1) just add a subview to your VC1 instead of using the VC2; 2) use push segue to VC2 instead of presenting it modally.

Comment: What is your Storyboard Segue Kind? (Show, Present Modally...)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Modally.